# Iterate though Columns of a Spark Dataframe and update specified values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

To iterate through columns of a Spark Dataframe created from Hive table and update all occurrences of desired column values, I tried the following code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val a: DataFrame = spark.sql(s"select * from default.table_a")

    val column_names: Array[String] = a.columns

    val required_columns: Array[String] = column_names.filter(name => name.endsWith("_date")) 

    val func = udf((value: String) => { if if (value == "XXXX" || value == "WWWW" || value == "TTTT") "NULL" else value } )

    val b = {for (column: String <- required_columns) { a.withColumn(column , func(a(column))) } a}
```

When executed the code in spark shell I got the following error.

```
scala> val b = {for (column: String <- required_columns) { a.withColumn(column , func(a(column))) } a}
<console>:35: error: value a is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
       val b = {for (column: String <- required_column_list) { a.withColumn(column , isNull(a(column))) } a}
                                                                                                          ^
```

Also I tried the following statement and didn't get required output.

```
val b = for (column: String <- required_columns) { a.withColumn(column , func(a(column))) }
```

The variable b is created a Unit instead of Dataframe.

```
scala> val b = for (column: String <- required_columns) { a.withColumn(column , func(a(column))) }
    b: Unit = ()
```

Please suggest any better way to iterate through the columns of Dataframe and update all occurances of values from columns or correct where I am wrong. Any other solution is also appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of *for loop*, you should go with `foldLeft`. And you don't need a `udf` function, `when` *inbuilt function* can be used

```
val column_names: Array[String] = a.columns

val required_columns: Array[String] = column_names.filter(name => name.endsWith("_date"))

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val b = required_columns.foldLeft(a){(tempdf, colName) => tempdf.withColumn(colName, when(col(colName) === "XXX" || col(colName) === "WWWW" || col(colName) === "TTTT", "NULL").otherwise(col(colName)))}
```

I hope the answer is helpful

## Explanation:

In
 `required_columns.foldLeft(a){(tempdf, colName) => tempdf.withColumn(colName, when(col(colName) === "XXX" || col(colName) === "WWWW" || col(colName) === "TTTT", "NULL").otherwise(col(colName)))}`

`required_columns` is an array of column names from `a` dataframe/dataset with `_date` as ending string, which are the `colName` inside `withColumn`

`tempdf` is the original dataframe/dataset i.e. `a`

[when function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#when-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.Object-) is applied inside `withColumn` which replaces all `XXX` or `WWWWW` or `TTTT` values to `NULL`

finally `foldLeft` returns all the *transformations applied dataframe* to `b`

Comment: Can you please explain the operation?

Comment: @Dwarrior,  explanation is added, I hope its clear now. If it is then please consider upvoting . thanks

Comment: Hi Ramesh Sir, I think this explanation was good. I posted a question in SO, not sure if I can leverage this method for resolving the same? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52239473/spark-dataframe-replace-tokens-of-a-common-string-with-column-values-for-each