# Spark dataframe - Replace tokens of a common string with column values for each row using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe with 3 columns - number (Integer), Name (String), Color (String). Below is the result of df.show with repartition option.

```
val df = sparkSession.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferschema", "true").option("delimiter", ",").option("decoding", "utf8").load(fileName).repartition(5).toDF()

+------+------+------+
|Number|  Name| Color|
+------+------+------+
|     4|Orange|Orange|
|     3| Apple| Green|
|     1| Apple|   Red|
|     2|Banana|Yellow|
|     5| Apple|   Red|
+------+------+------+
```

My objective is to create list of strings corresponding to each row by replacing the tokens in **common dynamic string** which I am passing as parameter to the method with the column values
For example: ***commonDynamicString*  = *Column.Name with Column.Color color***

In this string, my tokens are *Column.Name* and *Column.Color*. I need to replace these values for all the rows with respective values in that column. Note: this string can change dynamically hence hardcoding won’t work.

I **don't want to use RDD** unless no other option is available with dataframe.

Below are the approaches I tried but couldn't achieve my objective.

**Option 1:**

```
val a = df.foreach(t => {
 finalValue = commonString.replace("Column.Number", t.getAs[Any]("Number").toString())
          .replace("DF.Name", t.getAs("Name"))
          .replace("DF.Color", t.getAs("Color"))

          println ("finalValue: " +finalValue)
          })
```

With this approach, the finalValue prints as expected. However, I cannot create a listbuffer or pass the final string from here as a list to other function as foreach returns Unit
and spark throws error.

**Option 2:** I am thinking about this option but would need some guidance to understand if foldleft or window or any other spark functions can be used to create a 4th column called "Final"
using withColumn option and use a UDF where I can extract all the tokens using regex pattern matching - "Column.\w+" and do replace operation for the tokens?

```
+------+------+------+--------------------------+
|Number|  Name| Color|      Final               |
+------+------+------+--------------------------+
|     4|Orange|Orange|Orange with orange color  |
|     3| Apple| Green|Apple with Green color    |
|     1| Apple|   Red|Apple with Red color      |
|     2|Banana|Yellow|Banana with Yellow color  |
|     5| Apple|   Red|Apple with Red color      |
+------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

Can someone help me with this problem and also to let me know if I am thinking in the right direction to use spark for handling large datasets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can create a column method, say, `parseStatement` which takes a `String`-type statement and returns a `Column` with the following steps:

1. Parse the input `statement` to count number of tokens
2. Generate a Regex pattern in the form of `^(.*?)(token1)(.*?)(token2) ... (.*?)$`
3. Apply pattern matching to assemble a `colList` consisting of lit(`g1`), col(`g2`), lit(`g3`), col(`g4`), ..., where the `g?`s are the extracted Regex groups
4. [Concatenate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@concat(exprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) the Column-type items

Here's the sample code:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def parseStatement(stmt: String): Column = {
  val token = "Column."
  val tokenPattern = """Column\.(\w+)"""
  val literalPattern = "(.*?)"
  val colCount = stmt.sliding(token.length).count(_ == token)

  val pattern = (0 to colCount * 2).map{
    case i if (i % 2 == 0) => literalPattern
    case _ => tokenPattern
  }.mkString

  val colList = ("^" + pattern + "$").r.findAllIn(stmt).
    matchData.toList.flatMap(_.subgroups).
    zipWithIndex.map{
      case (g, i) if (i % 2 == 0) => lit(g)
      case (g, i) => col(g)
  }

  concat(colList: _*)
}

val df = Seq(
  (4, "Orange", "Orange"),
  (3, "Apple", "Green"),
  (1, "Apple", "Red"),
  (2, "Banana", "Yellow"),
  (5, "Apple", "Red")
).toDF("Number", "Name", "Color")

val statement = "Column.Name with Column.Color color"

df.withColumn("Final", parseStatement(statement)).
  show(false)
// +------+------+------+------------------------+
// |Number|Name  |Color |Final                   |
// +------+------+------+------------------------+
// |4     |Orange|Orange|Orange with Orange color|
// |3     |Apple |Green |Apple with Green color  |
// |1     |Apple |Red   |Apple with Red color    |
// |2     |Banana|Yellow|Banana with Yellow color|
// |5     |Apple |Red   |Apple with Red color    |
// +------+------+------+------------------------+
```

Note that `concat` takes column-type parameters, hence the need of [`col()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@col(colName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) for column values and [`lit()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@lit(literal:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) for literals.

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for the suggestion but in my case the string will be changing every time so I cannot hardcode any values. Can you provide me the generalized expression for both column names and lit values ? Also consider it to be like some executable statement, so what’s the best way to use spark to get all the values in Final column and execute each of these statements ?

Comment: Let’s say u have a select statement that needs to be built dynamically select * from table name where name = column.name and color = column.color. Another iteration can be  an update statement where my query structure would change but I still need to replace some tokens with respective value. For ex: if I see column.name in the query I need to replace column.name only with name column value. If it doesn’t have column.color I won’t derive color column. I could use the regex defined in my original query to get the values against tokens and replace. I am struggling with how to part in dataframe

Comment: I've updated the solution based on my understanding of your clarified requirement.

Comment: Thanks Leo for your guidance. I think above approach gives me some idea on how to create a new dataframe with new column using a function. I will test against some scenarios before marking the answer as correct. I have one more question - If the Final column has list of 1 Million queries instead of just simple statements and I want to execute them against database, what is the optimized way of using dataframe to execute each of them? This can be a different SO topic, however i was thinking of creating list of string from dataframe and using df.count to iterate over each query and execute.

Comment: Assuming those are standard SQL statements, one approach would be to save the statement column in a script file, like `df.select(parseStatement(statement)).coalesce(1).write.csv("/path/to/scriptfile")`, and run the script file in batch mode.  If applicable, you can even split the DataFrame by applying suitable filters (using `where` clauses) before processing and saving them into multiple script files for execution.

Comment: Hi Leo, Thank you for sample code. I learnt new and better ways of using scala functions and regex. One thing I would still like to understand is the pattern string that evaluates to => (.*?)DF\.(\w+)(.*?)DF\.(\w+)(.*?)DF\.(\w+)(.*?)DF\.(\w+)(.*?) --- What are my groups in this?. I was under the impression that my groups in regex are enclosed within parenthesis. Trying at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html gives me 9 groups, last one being empty. Can you please elaborate more. Secondly, I want to create list in-memory operation instead of writing to separate batch files.

Comment: Is this correct way of handling the execution of sql statements in memory?    var newFinalDF = newDF.select("Final")
    var count = newFinalDF.count
    var limit = 2


 while(count > 0){
          var partitionDF = newFinalDF.limit(limit)
         
   val localIterator = partitionDF.toLocalIterator
   while (localIterator.hasNext) {
   executeSQLStatement (localIterator.next())
   }
          newFinalDF = newFinalDF.except(partitionDF)
          count = count - limit
     }

Comment: Using this SQL statement `select Column.id, Column.name from product where Column.id > 100;` as an example, number of tokens is 3 hence the generated Regex pattern will consist of interleaving Regex groups of 3 `tokenPatterns` and 4 `literalPatterns`.  The extracted Regex groups will be: `(select )(id)(, )(name)( from product where )(id)( > 100;)`

Comment: To keep the the statements in memory, consider `collect`-ing them like `df.select(parseStatement(statement)).collect.map(_.getAs[String](0))`.  Note that this assumes memory capacity on the driver node is large enough to hold them.  To explore further on this topic, I would suggest that you post a separate question with specific requirement and sample data.

Comment: Thank you for all the guidance and explanation. Very helpful.